# call child data from firebase

Tags: xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Good evening,

I am trying to call data to post onto a card very similar to tinder. When I run my code, everything works and I see the print statement in the console. However the card view shows a default image with default text.
I was wondering if anyone has encountered this issue and could possibly help explain what I am doing wrong.

```
fileprivate func fetchUsersFromDatabase() {
    Database.database().reference().child("JobPost").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(Snapshot) in
        if let eachDict = Snapshot.value as? NSDictionary{
            for each in eachDict{

       //I think the issue is caused by the let post = poster
            let post = Poster(dictionary: Snapshot.value as! [String : Any])
            self.cardViewModels.append(post.toCardViewModel())
            print(each.value )
            }
            
        }
        self.setupDummyCards()
    }, withCancel: {(Err) in
  })
}
```

// the struct is in an extension file.

```
struct Poster: ProducesCardViewModel{
var jobName : String?
var price: Int?
var postName: String?
var ImageUrl1: String?
var uid: String?

init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
    self.price = dictionary["cost"] as? Int
    self.jobName = dictionary["category"] as? String
    self.postName = dictionary["description"] as? String ?? ""
    self.ImageUrl1 = dictionary["JobImageUrl"] as? String ?? ""
    self.uid = dictionary["fromId"] as? String ?? ""
}

func toCardViewModel() -> CardViewModel {
    let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: jobName ?? "", attributes: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 32, weight: .heavy)])
    let priceString = price != nil ? "\(price!)" : "N\\A"
    attributedText.append(NSAttributedString(string: "  \(priceString)", attributes: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 24, weight: .regular)]))
    let jobString = jobName != nil ? jobName! : "Not available"
    attributedText.append(NSAttributedString(string: "\n\(jobString)", attributes: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .regular)]))
    return CardViewModel(imageNames: [ImageUrl1 ?? "" ], attributedString: attributedText, textAlignment: .left)
 }
}
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qenA7.png)

// toCardViewModel

```
import UIKit

 protocol ProducesCardViewModel {
func toCardViewModel() -> CardViewModel
 }
    class CardViewModel {

let JobimageName: [String]
let attributedString: NSAttributedString
let textAlignment: NSTextAlignment

init(imageNames: [String], attributedString: NSAttributedString, textAlignment: NSTextAlignment) {
    self.JobimageName = imageNames
    self.attributedString = attributedString
    self.textAlignment = textAlignment
}

fileprivate var imageIndex = 0 {
    didSet {
        let imageName = JobimageName[imageIndex]
        let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
        imageIndexObserver?(imageIndex, image)
    }
}

var imageIndexObserver: ((Int, UIImage?) -> ())?

func advanceToNextPhoto() {
    imageIndex = min(imageIndex + 1, JobimageName.count - 1)
}

func goToPreviousPhoto() {
    imageIndex = max(0, imageIndex - 1)
}
}
```

Thank you in advance!

// P.S I previously posted this question without lack of sufficient detail. I decided to just re post it with the quality material. I really appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out an answer and it was quite obvious to me. I noticed that

```
print(each.value )
```

would print the value, so I just substituted

```
let post = Poster(dictionary: Snapshot.value as! [String : Any])
```

to

```
 let post = Poster(dictionary: each.value as! [String : Any])
```

and everything started to work just fine!